# Drupal Webform Submissions

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I have created a Job Application webform on Drupal and it contains the usual input fields: Name, Email and Attach CV. The form itself works fine, user completes the form and on submission both the user and myself an automated email acknowledging the submission.

Is there a way to:

1. Add a tick box next to each individual submission in Drupal
2. Email the selected users (preferably directly from Drupal)

Cheers for your help guys,
Rumman

Answer (score 0):

You can do all those using form_alter hook for the webform. Don't give this facility for anonymous users because anybody can make you send email to anybody else(spamming).